# Compression Rules to IPv6

Tags: ipv6

I'm having trouble compressing the IPv6 address: `8​b​f​a​:​9​9​f​0​:​d​4​c​5​:​0​b​8​c​:​0​f​6​f​:​0​4​d​f​:​2​8​0​4​:​2​8​3​d​`

I think it would be: `8bfa:99f:d4c5:b8c:f6f:4df:284:283d`

Unfortunately, this is not correct.

Comment: _[RFC 4291, Section 2.2. Text Representation of Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.2)_ explains the conventional IPv6 format rules, while _[RFC 5952, Section4. A Recommendation for IPv6 Text Representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952.html#section-4)_ explains the canonical IPv6 format rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like regular decimal numbers you work with every day, only leading zeros can be removed. Trailing zeros and zeros in the middle must stay.

If the other ones could be removed you wouldn't know whether `284` means `0284`, `2084`, `2804`, or `2840`.

Answer (score 2):

Hexa 99f0 canot be compressed to hexa 99f because they are not the same value.

Hexa 0b8c can be compressed to hexa b8c because left zeroes dont change both final value.

IPv6 address are composed of 8 groups of 4 hexa-digits. If two (or more) consecutives of them are 0000 you can supress they. E.G:

```
0111:0022:0003:0000:0000:0006:0070:0800 = 111:22:3::6:70:800
```

Comment: Per the standards track RFC 5952, "_The symbol "::" MUST NOT be used to shorten just one 16-bit 0 field. For example, the representation 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1 is correct, but 2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1 is not correct._"

Comment: Your comment is very timely. Sorry for the inconvenience, but it opens a gap to ask you something. Regarding this "::" rule, I have a question that I don't dare ask here, precisely because RFC 5952 are documented. I see some examples of professionals who use the simplification "::" for a single 16-bit hex group equal to to 0000, which is outside the norm. However, another rule prevents writing, for example, 1:2::5::8. According to the RFC 5952, it is clear that we are referring to the 1:2:0:0:5:0:0:8 and never to a 1:2:0:5:0:0:0:8 or a 1:2:0:0:0:5:0:8. Why can't we use such shortening?

Comment: And thanks for the tip Ron Maupin. The answer has been edited.

Comment: RFC 4291 allows you to shorten shorten just one 16-bit 0 field, but RFC 5952 changed some things allowed in RFC 4291. It also says that you need to accept any valid RFC 4291 format, but only output RFC 5952 format. You cannot use the `::` more than once because you would not know how many zero fields each represents. This has been the rule from the very start and  included in all the IPv6 RFCs for addressing: RFC 1884, obsoleted by RFC 2373, obsoleted by RFC 3513, obsoleted by the current RFC 4291, which has been updated by several RFCs, including RFC 5952.